# indicator function in objective function with $L_2$ norm

Tags: optimization, continuity, least-squares, quadratic-programming

I am trying to solve an optimization problem. The objective function is as follow

$arg\ min \lVert\mathbb{A}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}\rVert^2 + other\  linear\ least\ squares\ terms + \mathcal{I}(\mathit{x_0<a}) \lVert\mathit{x_0 - a}\rVert^2 +  \mathcal{I}(\mathit {x_n>b}) \lVert\mathit{x_n-b}\rVert^2$

$\mathcal{I}$ is the indicator function that returns 1 for true condition and 0 otherwise.

$x_0, x_1, ..., x_n$ should be between a and b.

If $x_0$ or $x_n$ is out of the range, one cost will be added to the objective function.

If the indicator function doesn't appear in the objective function, it's simply one linear least squares optimization problem and is simple to solve. Indicator function is not a continuous function and make the problem difficult.

I am not an expert on numerical optimization. Any hints, links and materials are appreciated.

Comment: Instead of looking at this problem as an "indicator function" and getting confused, notice that you simply have a function with numerous domains. Not only that, but the function as a whole remains continuous and smooth. It can be easily solved using optimization methods (at least first order methods), just like the regular least squares with squared $l_2$ penalty.

Comment: @iarbel84 Thanks for your reply. I don't fully understand your point. the function as a whole remains continuous and smooth. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Very generally speaking, the simplest iterative methods to solve an optimization problem require the function to be: 1) convex 2) differentiable. The function you present here is convex and also continuous. If you're unfamiliar with continuity we're a bit stuck. But most importantly, you can solve the problem using Gradient Descent, which is probably the simplest algorithm. Do not worry about the indicator function, it just means you have a "different" function over different intervals of $x_0, x_n$, but it's not a problem at all.

Comment: @iarbel84 How can I calculate the gradient if Gradient Descent is used?

Comment: The gradient is the vector of partial derivatives of a function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient. 
I'll answer separately on your specific question, as it's actually possible to solve it explicitly, without using an iterative scheme

Comment: @iarbel84 I am familiar with the definition of gradient for differentiable functions. However the current objective function is not continuous as what I understand. I don't know how to calculate the gradient for current objective function.

Comment: Do you use Matlab or Python? Would you prefer hard constraints on $x_i$ instead of the quadratic penalty terms? What are the dimensions of $A$?

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. I use Matlab and Python. I don't hope to change the objective function. The dimension of $A$ is about 15000x15000.

Comment: @littleO why are they non convex? The meaning of the first term (applies to the second as well) is that $f(x_0)=0$ if $x_0<a$ and $f(x_0)=(x_0-a)^2$ when $x_0>=a$. You can plot it on paper and see that it's convex, and for a formal proof it resembles the ReLU function which is also convex

Comment: @iarbel84 Oh, you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let: $$ f(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases}
&\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\|^2, &x_0\geq a, x_n\leq b \\
&\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\|^2 + (x_0-a)^2, &x_0<a, x_n\leq b \\
&\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\|^2 + (x_n-b)^2, &x_0\geq a, x_n>b \\
&\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\|^2+ (x_0-a)^2 + (x_n-b)^2, &x_0<a, x_n>b
\end{cases} $$
Then the gradient is:
$$ \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases}
&2A^T(A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}), &x_0\geq a, x_n\leq b \\
&2A^T(A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}) + 2I_0(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}), &x_0<a, x_n\leq b \\
&2A^T(A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}) + 2I_n(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}), &x_0\geq a, x_n>b \\
&2A^T(A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}) + 2I_0(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})+I_n(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}), &x_0<a, x_n>b
\end{cases} $$
where $I_i$ is a square matrix with $1$ on the $i$-th diagonal entry and of zeros elsewhere.

The optimal solution $\mathbf{x}^*$ is:
$$ \mathbf{x}^* = \begin{cases}
&(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\mathbf{b}, &x^*_0\geq a, x^*_n\leq b \\
&(A^TA+I_0)^{-1}(A^T\mathbf{b}+I_0\mathbf{a}), &x^*_0<a, x^*_n\leq b \\
&(A^TA+I_n)^{-1}(A^T\mathbf{b}+I_n\mathbf{b}), &x^*_0\geq a, x^*_n>b \\
&(A^TA+I_0+I_n)^{-1}(A^T\mathbf{b}+I_0\mathbf{a}+I_n\mathbf{b}), &x^*_0<a, x^*_n>b
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Also notice there might be some confusion here. I'm not sure what the indicator $a, b$ values should be. Are they related to the matrix $A$ and vector $\mathbf{b}$? If so, you need to indicate exactly to **which** entries there. As $x_0, x_n$ are scalars, it is as if you're comparing a scalar to a vector. If they are not related to the matrix, it's better to change them to some other notation, say $\alpha, \beta$.

Comment: Thanks. $a$ and $b$ are not related to the matrix $A$ and $\mathbf{b}$. Do you mean that I need to compute four optimal solutions and select the minimun from them? I am not familiar with optimization of nondifferentiable functions. Could you provide some links to introductory materials?

Comment: You need to compute $\mathbf{x}^*$ for all 4 equations and see for which one it meets the constrains on $a,b$. This is a differentiable function. If you approve the answer please tick it with $\checkmark$

Comment: Boyd's free Convex Analysis book is a good place to start on optimization. It's free and available online: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/

Comment: Thanks. I already have the book. However, I lack some practical experience. In fact, the number of variables like $x_0$ and $x_n$  is large. I am not sure the method you give is feasible for such situation

Comment: You can add the same "penalty" for each of the variables exactly in the same way I did it for $x_0,x_n$. BTW what exactly is you model? Why are you using this type of function/penalty?

Comment: For two optimization variables, four optimal solutions need to be computed. The number of optimal solutions will be very large if the optimization variables such $x_0$ and $x_n$ is more than 100. I am trying one agrithm from one paper. If you could leave your email, I can send the paper to you.

Comment: How do you know that there is a solution that falls within its own interval?

Comment: @LinAlg Sorry. I don't catch what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rename your parameters $a$ and $b$ to $x_l$ and $x_u$ to avoid confusion with the vector $b$. You can phrase your problem as a quadratic optimization (QO) problem:
$$\min_{x,u,v}\left\{||Ax-b||^2+||u||^2+||v||^2 : u\geq x-x_u, v\geq x_l-x, u\geq 0, v\geq 0\right\}.$$
At optimality, $u_i=\max\{0, x-x_u\}$ (so $u_i=0$ if $x \leq x_u$), and $v_i=\max\{0, x_l-x\}$ (so $v_i=0$ if $x \geq x_l$).

There are many different solvers available for QO problems. YALMIP and CVXPY are modeling tools that allow you to enter a QO in the form above, but they have a memory overhead that might be prohibitive for your problem size. More memory efficient interfaces typically allow only a single variable $x$, forcing you to express the objective and constraints in the following way:
$$\min_x \Biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix}x\\u\\v\end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix}A^TA & O & O \\ O & I & O \\ O & O & I\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\u\\v\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}-2b \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix}x\\u\\v\end{pmatrix} + b^Tb : \\
 \begin{pmatrix}I & -I & O \\ -I & O & -I \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\u\\v\end{pmatrix} \leq \begin{pmatrix}x_u e \\ -x_l e\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}x\\u\\v\end{pmatrix} \geq \begin{pmatrix}-\infty \\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Biggl\}$$

In Matlab, you can solve this in the following way:

```
n = 5000;
m = 5000;
A = rand(m, n);
b = rand(m, 1);

x_l = 0;
x_u = 1;

H = blkdiag(A'*A, eye(n), eye(n));
f = [-2*b; zeros(2*n,1)];
Aineq = [eye(n) -eye(n) zeros(n,n); -eye(n) zeros(n,n) -eye(n)];
bineq = [x_u * ones(n,1); -x_l * ones(n,1)];

[x,fval] = quadprog(H,f,Aineq,bineq,[],[],[-inf(n,1); zeros(2*n,1)],[]);
```

This solves in around 45 seconds, so if your machine has enough memory and you increase the size to 15000 x 15000, I think it should solve within an hour.

Comment: You introduce two new optimization variables and convert the indicator function into inequaltiy constraints between optimization varialbes? The original optimization problem becomes a constrained least squares problem?

Comment: @JoggingSong that's right, an *in*equality constrained LS problem. The extra variables ensure that the Lagrangian is twice continuously differentiable (and self-concordant).

Comment: Do you suggest that Lagrange multiplier can be used to solver the problem? Do Lagrange multiplier can handle inequality constraint?

Comment: @JoggingSong yes (look for the Wikipedia article on KKT conditions), but the problem is too large to solve by hand; use software for constrained quadratic optimization as indicated

Comment: I have a simple question after reading some materials on constrained optimization. For one constrained optimization, the only choice for me is to convert a contrained optimization problem to a unconstrained optimization problem by some way?

Comment: @JoggingSong No, you never have to convert it to an unconstrained problem. There are algorithms for constrained optimization problems, such as interior point methods.

Comment: The new optimization variables $u$ and $v$ are dependent on the original variables $x$. Will this be a problem?

Comment: @JoggingSong not as long as you optimize over all variables simultaneously, like in the Matlab code

Comment: When can a new optimization variable introduced without causing any problem? There are several methods for quadratic programming from the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming. Can you suggest a method if A is a sparse matrix?

Comment: @JoggingSong what kind of problem? Adding a new variable never causes theoretical issues, although it can affect performance positively and negatively; if $A$ is sparse it can help to add yet another variable $w$ with the constraint $Ax=w$, and using $w^Tw$ in the objective instead of $x^T(A^TA)x$. Interior point methods are good, cplex/gurobi/mosek all have good implementations.

Comment: I don't know when a new optimization variable can be introduced, so I am always afraid that it may cause some problem. Is there any links or materials on this?

Comment: @JoggingSong any book on linear optimization (such as the one by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis) should cover reformulations, and such tricks often extend to nonlinear optimization

Comment: Thanks. Is this a common practice to tackle indicator function?

Comment: @JoggingSong yes, I cannot think of any other way

Comment: It seems that interior-point method is fast for large sparse QP compared with active set method from some material. However maybe I need to implement interior-point method by myselft. Is the interior-point method a little difficult to implement?

Comment: @JoggingSong an interior-point method is routinely implemented as part of a master's program and can be written in under 50 lines of Python code. That will be a simple routine that does not exploit sparsity. Something more advanced can take months or years to implement :)

Comment: From the perspective of implementation, augmented Lagrangian method is preferred?

Comment: @JoggingSong that completely depends on the problem.

Comment: @LinAlg Why not just use gradient descent or an accelerated gradient descent method such as FISTA? The original unconstrained problem has a differentiable (and convex) objective function.

Comment: @littleO first order methods are typically slower than Newton based methods, but I agree that gradient based methods can be used too