# Implementation method selection for sparse constrained linear least squares or quadratic programming

Tags: least-squares, quadratic-programming

I need to slove one optimization problem of quadratic programming. The number of optimization variables is about 16,000. The constraints include equality constraints and inequality constraints.

I have no such practical experiences before. There are are three choices for the probelm after reading some materials:

```
active set method,     
interior point method
augmented Lagrangian method
```

I need implement the optimization algorithm on my own.

Active set method is not suitable for such problem size.
Interior point method is fast but difficult to implement from the link:
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14228/rank-deficient-nnls?noredirect=1&lq=1
*A first order method (Augmented Lagrangian, ADMM, split Bregman, etc.) These are possible to implement yourself without needing to use a packaged library.*
So augmented Lagrangian method will be my choice. How about my analysis?
Most materials I find is about augmented Lagrangian method with equality constraints. Can you recommand any links or materials on augmented Lagrangian method with inequality constraints?

Comment: Try reading Boyd's manuscripts on proximal algorithms and on ADMM.

Comment: @littleO It looks like that proximal algorithms is used to slove nonsmooth optimization problems. Do you mean the original objectve function will become a nonsmooth one if agumented Lagrangian methods are selected for inequaltiy constrained problem?

Comment: The augmented Lagrangian method and ADMM are both proximal algorithms, and those manuscripts will show you how to use them to solve your optimization problem. Proximal algorithms are also useful for constrained optimization problems with a smooth objective function. Also note that constrained problems can be viewed as non-smooth unconstrained problems by enforcing a constraint $x \in C$ with an indicator function term $I_C(x)$ in the objective function. Here $I_C$ is the convex indicator function of the convex set $C$.

Comment: @littleO Thanks. I will read the paper carefully. Do augmented Lagrangian method and ADMM can run efficiently on mobile phone?

Comment: How fast do you need it to be solved? I'd be curious to see your problem written in detail. (I'd also be curious to hear what the application is if you don't mind sharing.)

Comment: @littleO Maybe 1~2s is OK. The problem is described in another post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780680/indicator-function-in-objective-function-with-l-2-norm/3790834?noredirect=1#comment7966396_3790834. The application is like this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182242/Transforming-Images-for-Fun-A-Local-Grid-based-Ima. The warped grid is generated by solving one constrained least squares optimization problem.

Comment: @littleO $proximal algorithms can be viewed as an analogous tool for nonsmooth,  constrained,  large-scale,  or  distributed versions of these problems$ However, the paper seems to focus on nonsmooth objective functions. How are equality and inequality constraints are handled? I am going to read your ph.d thesis if I have time.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The matrix A is very sparse and there maybe be about ten non-zero elements per row. After I have read the paper proximal algorithms, I still don't know how to handle constrains. Can you suggest any links or introductory materials?

Comment: @littleO In your ph.d thesis, it seems that your optimization problem only incude linear equality constraints. How is the time required for your problem?

Comment: I was wrong when I said the problem was non-convex.

Comment: Looking at the other thread, it appears to me now that you are solving an unconstrained problem with a differentiable objective function. For that you could use gradient descent or, even better, an accelerated gradient descent algorithms (such as FISTA). What are the constraints? I don't see any constraints in the problem given in the other thread.

Comment: @littleO The original problem has several indicator functions, so the objective fucntion is nonsmooth. The accepted answer converts indicator function into constraints, and it is reformlated as constrained least squares problem.

Comment: The function $h(x) = \mathcal I(x_0 < a) (x_0 - a)^2$ is a smooth function, though. It is differentiable.  (It's also convex, which is nice too.) Same for the other term in the objective function that involves an indicator function. The comments by iarbel84 are insightful.

Comment: Ok, my recommendation is to first solve your original unconstrained problem using gradient descent. That's pretty simple to implement. Once you have that working, you can use an accelerated gradient descent method (I would use FISTA). That is only a small modification to the gradient descent code and it will probably converge much faster. If $A$ is very sparse and you don't need a highly accurate solution, then you might be able to solve it in a few seconds (but this depends a lot on how sparse $A$ is).

Comment: Thanks. The point is that I can't figure out $h(x)$ is a smooth function. I understant that $h(x)$ is continuous and convex. Do you agree that indicator function itself is not smooth?

Comment: Yes, the indicator function itself is non-smooth.  A good example to think about is the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ if $x \geq a$ and $f(x) = (x-a)^2$ if $x < a$. Try graphing that function. You'll see it's smooth.

Comment: @littleO Finally I catch you what you mean. $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. The derivative at $x=0$ is also contious and both equals $0$ from two sides. so f is smooth.

Answer (score 1):

@littleO has pointed you to the right [references](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/admm.html). And below is a simple trick for converting inequality constraints into equality constraints:

$$Ax \le b \quad \mbox{means} \quad Ax - b = t, \quad t \le 0.$$

Comment: I have no much experience on numerical optimization. Is the reformulation  easy to solve? There is still bound constraints on $t$.

Comment: @JoggingSong What’s exactly the problem you need to solve?

Comment: I need use the grids to warp one image. The grids are obtained by one constrained least squares optimization problem.